# multiple static varibles with same name in C

Tags: c, static-variables

can we have multiple declaration of static varibles in C as below?
if yes how it works?

```
main()

{

   static int a=1;  

       ptrFun();

   a+=1;

   ptrFun();

   printf(" %d \n",a);

}

void ptrFun()

{

   static int a=2;  

   int b=1;

   a+=++b;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

> can we have multiple declaration of static varibles in C as below? if yes how it works?

Yes, this is perfectly fine. It works by the compiler associating variable names with a particular **scope**. Two static function-local variables of the same name but in different functions are not in conflict because they are defined in different scopes, and their memory is assigned separately.